# How to make my diagnostic app connect to a USB device that has been opened earlier by a win service, in C# .NET

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, usb-drive, local-system-account

This is a medical lab instrument (our product) connected to a Windows 7 system via a USB port and it is controlled by an application launched by a windows service right after power up.

My goal is to be able to diagnose instrument problems by running a simple application in parallel with the main application. The communication with the instrument is achieved through a server (in a single threaded apartment) that ultimately talks to a COM object.

In my diagnostic application I am following the same steps as the main application to connect to the instrument.

After the first few tries, I realized that the processes related to the instrument run under system account while my application under user account. I stopped the service of the main application and changed its login property to match that of the user account. My diagnostic application still fails to connect to the USB device.

I am ninety percent of time a firmware developer and my head spins when I have to deal with the jungle of a windows system. What makes me cringe from frustration is that there is one scenario in which this all works but that scenario is only to debug the main application yet it doesn't work in user mode.

If the main application is not started by the windows service but by a console app, thus all processes are under user account, my diagnostic application works beautifully.

What is the difference between the two scenarios as far as using the same device server by two concurrent applications that are running under the same user account?

Thank you.

Comment: Would you happen to have some kind of block diagram showing the various components in the system ? Though I think I understand your wording, a diagram would confirm the architecture.

Comment: I believe it depends on how the COM object is implemented.  I'm not familiar with the details, but the most likely requirements are: (a) same Remote Desktop session; (b) same logon session; (c) same window station; or (d) same desktop.  Note that none of these possible requirements are met in your first scenario, and they are all met in your second scenario.  The upshot is the same in any case - you'll have to either run both applications interactively, or both as a service.  Also, the services may need to both be configured to log in as local system.